# Multiply Two items and result self generate in Third

Tags: javascript, css, html

When I have multiply two items result is generate in third input box but problem is that when i add one more row on click add button this multiply not work..I want to when add next row it also work and also want to discount code in next.........please help me about this because this is problems create in my projects and my work is stop
**HTML**

```js
var maxID = 0;
    function getTemplateRow() {
    var x = document.getElementById("templateRow").cloneNode(true);
    x.id = "";
    x.style.display = "";
    x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace(/{id}/, ++maxID);
    return x;
    }
    function addRow(btn) {
    var t = document.getElementById("theTable");
    var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var r = rows[rows.length - 1];
    r.parentNode.insertBefore(getTemplateRow(), r);

    }
    function update(){
    var price = document.getElementById("Uprice").value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    var Tprice = price * quantity ;

    document.getElementById("Totprice").value = Tprice;
    }
    function removeRow(btn) {
      var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
      row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    }
```

```css
th{
border: 3px 3px 3px 3px green;
position: relative;
background-color: green;
color: white;
width: 300px;

}
```

```html
<table id="theTable">
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>name</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="" name=""></td>
    <td><input type="" name=""></td>
    <td><input type="" name=""></td>
    <td><input type="" name=""></td>
    <td><input type="" name=""></td>
    <td><input type="" name=""></td>


    </tr>
    <button onclick="addRow();">add</button>
    <tr id="templateRow" style="display:none;">
    <!--<td>{id}</td>-->
    <td><input /></td>
    <td><input type="" name="">
        <!--<select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>-->
    </td>
    <td><input id = "Uprice"/></td>
    <td><input id = "quantity" onChange="update()"/></td>
    <td><input id = "Totprice" readonly=""/></td>
    <td><input /></td>
    <td><input /></td>
    <td><input /></td>
    <td><button  onclick="removeRow(this);">delete</button></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I suggest you use `class` instead of `id` for using multi row

Comment: i use class but this not work.....

Comment: Please update your code. I will try to help

Comment: How update??  this is code in which We want to changinging.....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is update function is binded to current DOM elements but not the new one's.
So, Rebind the `update function` to the newly added element.

`To do that you can simply reinitialize your update function and call it as per your appropriate trigger or you can even destroy it and reinitialize it but make sure you have your triggers in proper place`.

Answer (score 1):

id should be unique. So if multiple same id exists, in this case Uprice, quantity, Totprice and templateRow, only the first one works.

So you can change id to class, and getElementByClassName, then all items with the classname will be executed. That should work.

Comment: thank you for answering ......we use this but this not work even the firsr row....if  all id's like table id also change to class??

Comment: I think you'll need to change update() to update(this), just like how you do about remove(this). 
And then update TotPrice like td.parentNode.parentNode.value = Tprice 
So it knows which row it is multiplying and updating. Same for quantity and price in update(). You should read data according to 'this'.

Comment: we also use this in update but not work...can you help me and change in my code and then upload